# Named semaphores in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore, cross-process

I have a script in python which uses a resource which can not be used by more than a certain amount of concurrent scripts running.

Classically, this would be solved by a named semaphores but I can not find those in the documentation of the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module or [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading) .

Am I missing something or are named semaphores not implemented / exposed by Python? and more importantly, if the answer is no, what is the best way to emulate one?

Thanks,
Boaz

PS. For reasons which are not so relevant to this question, I can not aggregate the task to a continuously running process/daemon or work with spawned processes - both of which, it seems, would have worked with the python API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a third party extension like [these](http://semanchuk.com/philip/PythonIpc/), ideally the `posix_ipc` one -- see in particular the [semaphore](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/#semaphore) section in the docs.

These modules are mostly about exposing the "system V IPC" (including semaphores) in a unixy way, but at least one of them (`posix_ipc` specifically) is claimed to work with Cygwin on Windows (I haven't verified that claim).  There are some documented [limitations](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/#platforms) on FreeBSD 7.2 and Mac OSX 10.5, so take care if those platforms are important to you.

Comment: In 2023, is the Python library's `multiprocessing` module adequate?

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate them by using the filesystem instead of a kernel path (named semaphores are implemented this way on some platforms anyhow).  You'll have to implement `sem_[open|wait|post|unlink]` yourself, but it ought to be relatively trivial to do so.  Your synchronization overhead might be significant (depending on how often you have to fiddle with the semaphore in your app), so you might want to initialize a ramdisk when you launch your process in which to store named semaphores.

Alternatively if you're not comfortable rolling your own, you could probably wrap `boost::interprocess::named_semaphore` ([docs here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_semaphore.html)) in a simple extension module.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to get this wrong (fairness, scheduling wakeup, race conditions).  Use kernel or libc primitives (eg. the real sem_* API, or the CreateSemaphore/event API in windows); avoid rolling your own synchronization primitives.

Comment: This is why I offer that you could use boost if you're not comfortable rolling your own.

Comment: @NickBastin Is there any way at all to "roll your own"? (Short of wrapping libc or Boost?) You said "You'll have to implement `sem_[open|wait|post|unlink]` yourself, but it ought to be relatively trivial to do so" but, the question of (non-)triviality aside, how exactly would you do that in light of possible race conditions? How would you ensure atomicity of semaphore operations?